# PHP sqltie: Unable to open database with 500 error running on apache2

Tags: php, sqlite, apache

I've created a php file to display contents of sqlite database on apache2

```php
<?php
    $connection = new SQLite3('/root/database/clients.db');
    if($connection){
        echo "Connected\n";
    }
    $results = $connection->query('SELECT * FROM USER_LIST');
    while($row=$results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
        echo 'user = ' . $row['user'] . '<br>';
        echo 'period = ' . $row['period'] . '<br>';
        echo 'status = ' . $row['status'] . '<br>';

    }
?>
```

Running this script directly from cli works:

```bash
php -f /var/www/html/index.php
```

However when i try to execute it on `apache2` it throws `HTTP ERROR 500`

My apache2 error log:

[Tue Oct 17 00:53:13.649296 2023] [php:error] [pid 416648] [client 122.161.69.12:11908] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Unable to open database: unable to open database file in /var/www/html/index.php:2\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/index.php(2): SQLite3->__construct()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 2

Apache2 version: `Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)` | Php version: `8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14`

Comment: This smells like it could be permissions related. Can you verify that the web server user has the appropriate access to the fille? (`chown`/`chmod`)

Comment: I placed my database file and php script in same folder `var/www/html` and it worked but i want to know how do i allow apache2 to access files outside html folder?